# SQL Bulk insert bit column

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I have a column in the table Person

```
IsApproved bit NULL,
```

I have a class Person with below property

```
bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
```

When I try to bulk insert values in Person table with Person.IsApproved value set to null, it gives the below exception.

```
cannot change datatype of a column once it has data.
```

Please help me how to store NULL value in the IsApproved column using bulk insert.

Comment: Show us the code you are using to bulk insert.

Comment: Code: SqlBulkCopyHelper.BulkInsert<Persons>(_db, persons). Where persons are the List<Persons>

Answer (score -2):

Set `Person.IsApproved` from `null` to `System.DBNull.Value` in visual studio.

Comment: You can't set a Boolean, even a nullable one, to `System.DBNull.Value`.

Comment: IsApproved is a bool? field. Assigning DBNull.Value gives "cannot implicitly convert type system.dbnull to bool?" error